# Log current page url with NLog

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I'm trying to log the current pages URL as part of our NLog layout. I've scoured the NLog layout variables and have come up with nothing.

Does anyone know how to get the current page URL as a variable for the layout? Also is it possible just to extract the domain name so this can be used in the EventLog source attribute?

Comment: Follow up: I used ${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_NAME} to get the domain

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [Aspnet-request layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspRequest-Layout-Renderer).

```
<target xsi:type="Trace" 
            name="trace" 
          layout="${message} ${aspnet-request:serverVariable=Url}" />
```

You have full access to the [request properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx).

Comment: Does not log the query string

Comment: @PsychoDad see other URL variables at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx

Comment: this approach will return only URL without query string. Maybe NLog version matters what works as of today...

Comment: Here you have the list of the server variables: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx

Answer (score 8):

I tested many approached and only "item" seems to work in regards to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx

method = ${aspnet-request:**item**=HTTP_METHOD}

url **with query string** = ${aspnet-request:**item**=HTTP_URL}

user agent / browser = ${aspnet-request:**item**=HTTP_USER_AGENT}

and so on...

**UPDATE**

Additionally to my answer above (I don't remember if I knew it back then or not) but I found somewhere (also don't remember where, was a while ago) that ***NLog.Extended.dll*** must be also referenced to use functionality relevant to ASP.NET logging ie. layouts with `${aspnet-...`

Comment: Further to this. You will also need to have NLog.Web installed, too.

Answer (score 5):

Answer for .NET Core as I tried the above before finding that the above does not work for .NET Core

```
THE FOLLOWING DO NOT WORK FOR .NET CORE

${aspnet-request:serverVariable=Url}
${aspnet-request:item=HTTP_URL}
```

Instead use:

```
${aspnet-request-url}
${aspnet-request-querystring}
```

e.g.

```
    <target name="jsonFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="log.json" archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence" archiveAboveSize="5000000" maxArchiveFiles="10">
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
        <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
        <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
        <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
        <attribute name="exception" layout="${exception:format=ToString,StackTrace:maxInnerExceptionLevel=2}" />
        <attribute name="machineName" layout="${machinename}" />
        <attribute name="ip" layout="${aspnet-request-ip}" />
        <attribute name="method" layout="${aspnet-request-method}" />
        <attribute name="url" layout="${aspnet-request-url}" />
        <attribute name="query" layout="${aspnet-request-querystring}" />
        <attribute name="postedBody" layout="${aspnet-request-posted-body}" />
        <attribute name="userAgent" layout="${aspnet-request-useragent}" />
      </layout>
    </target>
```

For more see:
https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=package:nlog.web.aspnetcore